# Script to uninstall a folder from within C:\ProgramData\folder (GUID)

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, script

I'm hoping to find a script to uninstall a folder from within the `ProgramData` folder ie.. `C:\ProgramData\folder (GUID)`. As you can see the folder also has a GUID string this is what I have:

```
rmdir /s /q "%programdata%\Folder (asterisk)
```

I've tried a wildcard like this.. `(*)`, I've searched Google.. but I'm guessing my search is not phrased correctly as I cannot find a solution for the removal of the folder with the GUID string included. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Most of the machines this is for will be Windows 7 Pro x86/x64 and a few Vista same flavors.

Comment: Your `rmdir` command is missing a trailing `"` character. Have you tried `rmdir /s /q "%programdata%\Folder*"`?. You will probably need to run this as an Administrator as ordinary users do not have write access to `%programdata%`

Comment: Yeah, I guess the paste must of missed the " at the end.. but it is there and I am running as admin. The \Folder* did not work but thank you for the reply.